# Understanding object destructuring {foo: bar} = {baz: true} from MDN

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) an example says:

```js
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p, q} = o;

console.log(p); // 42
console.log(q); // true 

// Assign new variable values
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42
console.log(bar); // true
```

What is the point of doing `{p: foo, q: bar} = o;` if `{foo, bar} = o;` is the same? what's the use of `:` here?

Thanks

Comment: Please checkout below tutorial https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/

Comment: They are not the same. `{foo, bar} = o` is `foo = o.foo, bar = o.bar` whereas `{p: foo, q: bar} = o` is `foo = o.p, bar = o.q`

Comment: You have to do `{p: foo, q: bar} = o;` because the keys in object `o` are `p` and `q`.

Comment: it allows you to give your own name to the variable (so that it doesn't need to be exactly the same as the property). It is especially useful when dealing with `const` variables

Comment: It's like an alias that you can give to the variable name. You can then use it to access the variable with the new name you've set.

Comment: the comment in your example code "`// Assign new variable values`" is wrong, it's not assigning new values, but new variable names

Comment: `{p, q} = o` is the exact same as `{p: p, q: q} = o`

Comment: `var {p} = {p: 42, q: true};` means "take the key `p` from the object and assign it to a variable `p`". `var {foo} = {p: 42, q: true};` would similarly means 
"take the key `foo` from the object and assign it to a variable `foo`"...but there is no key `foo`. How is the interpreter to know you mean "actually, take one of the existing keys". And how would it know *which one*?

Comment: Sorry, now i understand! Thanks